# "already since a while" - is this proper English?

Tags: clauses

Consider the following sentence

> This and that is the situation, **already since a while**.

Question 1: Does this sound right to a native speaker?

Question 2: How could I find this out myself? I did a Google search on "already since a while" with only 11k results which indicates that it's at least not common.

**EDIT following the comments**: In my native language, German, we say "schon seit einer Weile". My question is whether the word-by-word translation of this sounds right in English.

Comment: What really do you want to imply by "already since a while"? The phrase is not ungrammatical and it doesn't fail to make sense. So where's your problem? Can you expand?

Comment: *This and that* seems strange to me. (I keep thinking of the expression *this, that, and the other thing.*) If I were to reinterpret, I would think *this has been the situation for a while*, but I'm not certain what you're actually trying to say, so I don't know if that's accurate.

Comment: Is your native language Spanish by any chance? The phrase "already since a while" looks a lot like "desde hace ya" which is stated in English as "for some time now."

Comment: In English, unlike some other European languages, 'since' is used only in the sense of 'from a certain date, time or occurrence until now'. _I've been here since two o'clock. Nobody has passed since I arrived here_  We don't say 'since a period of time'. I agree that Jason's version is the most idiomatic.

Comment: @Shoe, please turn your comment into an answer!

Comment: "schon seit einer Weile" --> "for a while now" https://translate.google.com/#auto/en/%22schon%20seit%20einer%20Weile%22

Comment: "My question is whether the word-by-word translation of this sounds right in English." No. As someone familiar with English and a smattering of German, I can say that there are idiomatic expressions that cannot be translated word-for-word between the two languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single German word *seit* has two possible translations in English: *since* and *for*. As Kate Bunting points out *since* is used when a starting point is stated or implied. And *for* is used when the duration is specified.

Another difference between English and German is that English typically uses the present perfect in such contexts, whereas in German the simple present is used. My translation of the sentence '*Das ist die Situation schon seit einer Weile* would be *This has been the situation for some time now*. You could also say '... *for a while now*'.

Google returns over 26 million results on the phrase '*for some time now*', and 21 million for '*for a while now*'.

As to your second question: ask a native speaker if you know one. Or do what you have done and ask on this site or on the sister *English Language Learners* site: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Comment: See also my comments at OP.